# How to easily handle a /dev/input events in Linux using F#

Tags: linux, events, f#, mono, system.reactive

I try to write a event-driven program with Rx and Rxx that works with devices in embedded linux (like gyroscope). It's supposed to react on simple file manipulation. Is there a way to handle a Linux low level events?

(An example would be highly appreciated)

Comment: You could have a look at the documentation for the [Mono.Unix](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=N%3aMono.Unix) assembly -- it provides an API for syscalls, file descriptors, etc. It doesn't have anything for Rx, but you might be able to implement that on top of the Mono.Unix API.

Comment: Maybe the FileSystemWatcher class would be useful in this case?

Comment: You can always call the C library with `P/invoke`

Comment: The FileSystemWatcher has lots of edge cases so watch out if you use that.  Its not as stable on Mono, and the MS one is not much better.